# Do melee attacks provoke attacks of opportunity from other combatants?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

I know that ranged or unarmed attacks provoke Attacks of Opportunity, but consider this case.

There's an enemy one space north of me, and one space east, both threatening and threatened by me. If I attack the enemy to the east with a melee attack, does that provoke an AoO from the enemy to the north?

Comment: It's about time you choose an answer, sir.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't. Opportunity Attacks are provoked ONLY by the following:

> The opportunity attack action is provoked by an enemy leaving an
>   adjacent square without shifting or teleporting, or by an adjacent
>   enemy using a ranged or area power.

See page 290 of the PHB.

Note that this means that unarmed strikes ALSO don't provoke opportunity attacks in 4th edition. This used to be the case in other editions, but not in this one.

Comment: Also for people used to other editions, standing up doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity either.

Comment: There are a handful of powers which present exceptions to the above with language such as, "the target provokes opportunity attacks when shifting (save ends)" or, "this attack does not provoke opportunity attacks." Additionally, the popular feat Staff Expertise prevents a staff-wielder from provoking due to making ranged or area attacks, and the popular Badge of the Berserker item prevents one from provoking while charging.